# VBA how to split headings by 'Regex'

Tags: regex, vba, split

I would like to split some 'Headings' from file but the format is so tricky as it has plenty of delimiter, such as tab, space, fullstop...

```
Part 1—About
1 Intro(Tab)
Part 1A.1 Functions
81.1.1 Application
5A use
```

I am thinking of whether (1)use regex to 'pre-set' the delimiter dictionary or (2) **split by the last occurrence of a 'number'** , but not sure if regex could achieve that.

what I would like to achieve is to separate title number and title name, such as:

```
Part 1       About
1            Intro
Part 1A.1    Functions
81.1.1       Application
5A           Use
```

Much appreciate for any help!

Comment: Could you elaborate how you exactly want to split your data, what you have tried so far and what exactly your question is. Likely it is possible with a RegEx, alternatively with a small piece of code (that likely will involve the `Split`-function), but before you even start, you need to define clear rules *how* you need your data.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I'd like to edit but the system says too many pending edit.. what I want is split to like ```Part1  About /1 Intro/
Part 1A.1   Functions
81.1.1   Application``` to split index with title name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function splitCharStr(str As String) As String
   Dim ret As Object, r
   With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d+)(?!.*\d)"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set ret = .Execute(str)
            splitCharStr = .replace(str, ret(0) & "||")
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `(?!.*\d)` - negative lookahead:
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

It will find the last occurrence of a number and **replace it with that number plus "||"**, as splitting character.

It can be used in the next way:

```
Sub testSplitString()
  Dim x As String, strSplit As String, arr
  x = "abcd23rt6y"
  'x = "1 Intro(Tab)"
  'x = "Part 1A.1 Functions"
  'x = "81.1.1 Application"
 strSplit = splitCharStr(x)
 arr = Split(strSplit, "||")

 Debug.Print Join(arr, vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Uncomment each "x" code line and run the testing code...

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**

The next version shows how to process a range of such strings (in column A:A), returning the split parts in the next columns (B:C):

```
Sub splitAColumn()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, strSpl, arrSpl, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastR).Value2 'B:C should be empty
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        strSpl = splitCharStr(CStr(arr(i, 1)))
        If strSpl <> "" Then
            arrSpl = Split(strSpl, "||")
            arr(i, 2) = arrSpl(0): arr(i, 3) = Trim(arrSpl(1))
        End If
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array content, at once:
  sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! but it only prints the left part from my side like ```Part 1```, and what if I would like to select a range to split but not just one string?

Comment: @Yuki What do you mean by "only prints the left part"? Did you look in `Immediate Window`? It shows/prints **two lines, each split part on its own line**. When you say "a range", do you mean a column? If so, how would you like it to return? In the following columns to the right? If not, how/where? The testing sub was only an example for testing the function itself...

Comment: @Yuki Didn't you find some time to clarify the issue? In the meantime I edited the above answer and place one (after **Edited**) able to process a range (from column A:A). Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: thank you so much for your elaborate answers and help! I really want to edit the question but only the website show I am not able to edit until now, really no idea why that happens. thanks again for your help but the ```splitAColumn``` returns error like ```Subscript out of range```

Comment: @Yuki When talk about an error you should also mention **on which code line it is raised**... The above code assumes that all cells value in the respective columns contain at least a digit. The code can handle such a situation, but **I need to know about it**... Do you have AnyDesk installed? If so, can I connect on your computer to see what's happening in your environment?

Comment: @Yuki You did not say anything about "prints the left part from my side". Did you understand how things works from the returning point of view? I adapted the last code to also handle the case when not any digit exists in the string to be processed, and it does not do anything in such a case. I man, it is not able to split on anything and `arr(1)` does not make any sense, that's why the potential error.

Comment: I just want to say a big thank you to you for your such elaborate explanations! sorry I am new for this and your explanation helps a lot, may I ask if "||" means space? for the previous what I mean left part is when I use range("A1:A2") to print the result

Comment: @Yuki No, the meaning of using "||" was to find a (rare) separator, very improbable to already exists in the string to be split. The VBA `Split` function creates an array by splitting a string by a specific separator (character)... Then, when you try calling a function, **you must pay attention to what parameter(s) it uses**. In this case, the function wait for a `String` (text). Calling it using a `Range` as parameter **cannot work**. As you can see, the last code version calls the function **once per each array element... Now, can I understand that the code did not answer your question?

Comment: @Yuki Being new here, I would like to inform you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the left code side check box in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, if somebody else searches for a similar issue it will know that the supplied solution works. Our main goal here is to make as many people as possible learning...

Comment: thank you! But I cannot accept answer as I am a new joiner this time, and I have got your idea for this, thank you again!

Comment: @Yuki You can and you already accepted it. The green check proves it... :)